# Managed kiosk devices are getting out of kiosk on launching the app with a specific key combination

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk-mode, kiosk, chromebook, google-admin-settings-api

We are a school in the US and we have developed an app for our students and we want our students to stick to that specific app only in chromebook devices. So we have an admin console and managed devices. So our apps launch in the kiosk mode but on the launch screen students can go out of the kiosk mode. And the worse thing is, it shows the exact  keys combination (ctrl+alt+s) on the launch screen and anybody can easily do it.

What we have tried to fix this.

we have also tried to login into chromeos and tried to disable the ctrl and alt keys, but after logout and login as enterprise enrollment, it still the same.

We have also tried to downgrade the version but it's still the same.

We want to have our students connects to our app in a single app and wont allow them to get out of it. Even if the student device goes out of power or internet password changed.

Any help on this problem. Thanks in advance